# Docker Compose for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to replicate this docker command in a **docker-compose.yml** file

```
docker run --name rails -d -p 80:3000 -v "$PWD"/app:/www -w /www -ti rails
```

My **docker-compose.yml** file:

```
rails:
    image: rails
    container_name: rails
    ports:
        - 80:3000
    volumes:
        - ./app:/wwww
```

When I'm doing **docker-compose up -d**, the container is created but it does not strat.

When I'm adding **tty: true** to my docker **docker-compose.yml** file, the container start well but my volume is not mounted.

How can I replicate excatly my docker command in a **docker-compose.yml**?

Comment: did you follow this https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/

Comment: you forst to need build `docker-compose build` then

Comment: No I did not follow docs.docker.com/compose/rails. I want to based my images on the Rails image. Your link does not do that.

Comment: docker-compose build, just build an image. It doesn't create the container. docker-composer up -d already does it, but also create the container.

Comment: The only difference I see between these two is that the docker-compose.yml is missing `workding_dir: /www`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answer. It helped me to find the solutions.

It was actually a volume problem. I wanted to mount the volume with the directory **/www**. But it was not possible.
So I used the directory used by default with the rails images:
**/usr/src/app**

```
rails:
    image: rails
    container_name: rails
    ports:
        - 80:3000
    working_dir: /usr/src/app
    volumes:
        - ./app:/usr/src/app
    tty: true
```

Now my **docker-compose up -d** command works

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways to solve your problem.

**Solution 1:** If you want to use the `rails` image in your docker-compose.yml, you need to set the command and working directory for it like

```
rails:
    image: rails
    container_name: rails
    command: bash -c "bundle install && rails server -b 0.0.0.0"
    ports:
        - 80:3000
    volumes:
        - ./app:/www
    working_dir: /www
```

This will create a new container from the rails image every time you run `docker-compose up`.

**Solution 2:** Move your docker-compose.yml to the same directory with Gemfile, and create `Dockerfile` in that directory in order to build a docker container in advance (to avoid running `bundle install`every time)

```
#Dockerfile
FROM rails:onbuild
```

I use `rails:onbuild` here for simplicity reasons (about the differences between `rails:onbuild` and `rails:<version>`, please see the [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/rails/)).

After that, modify the docker-compose.yml to

```
rails:
  build: .
  container_name: rails
  ports:
    - 80:3000
  volumes:
    - .:/www
  working_dir: /www
```

Run `docker-compose up` and this should work!

If you modify your Gemfile, you may also need to rebuild your container by `docker-compose build` before running `docker-compose up`.